# In uds, why need SOCK_STREAM when SOCK_DGRAM can guarantee no packet loss and no disorder?

Tags: linux, unix

> SOCK_STREAM, for a stream-oriented socket;
> SOCK_DGRAM, for a datagram-oriented socket that preserves message boundaries (as on most UNIX implementations, UNIX domain datagram sockets are always reliable and don't reorder datagrams);

From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html

Is the difference between the two just a packet size limit?